# Send File to API POST Request

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to send the file via API request, below is my code:

```
MultiValueMap<String, Object> body  = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
FileSystemResource file = new FileSystemResource("my_file_path");
body.add("dagFile", file);

HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity
        = new HttpEntity<>(body, headers);

RestTemplate restTemplate = restTemplate();

ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate
        .postForEntity(serverUrl, requestEntity, String.class);
```

Here i am providing the `file path` i.e file should be there present in the disk, is there any way via which i can create file in-memory and process my request :
Sudo Code :

```
    String filecontent = "12345";
    MultiValueMap<String, Object> body  = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    FileSystemResource file = new FileSystemResource(filecontent); // passing content as string
    body.add("dagFile", file);
```

Comment: See if this helps : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7925053/how-to-post-byte-array-via-resttemplate

Comment: It's seems to different from my issue.